# Rails devise when the user information belongs to Company devise

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a created a devise for Companies. I have made a table users, wish I want to store the user information password etc.. When a user sign up I want it to create a new user and a association to the Company.

My Company model:
has_one: User
My User model:
Belongs_to: Company

How should I overwrite the registration controller?

Best regards, 
Rails beginner

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I'm wrong here, but it sounds like companies won't be logging in — only users, which belong to a company.

With that in mind, you should have `User` as the Devise model instead of `Company`. Your associations, then, are correct. The next step would be to add fields for the user in the form for `company#new` using nested attributes (`fields_for` in the view; `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the model).

Answering your original question: you can use nested attributes to create a new user in the sign up form. You wouldn't need to override Devise's registration controller. Just modify the sign up form to include `fields_for` a user. Also, make sure the `Company` model has `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for the `User` model.

A quick aside: I'm not aware of the architecture of your application, but it seems like a `has_many` would be more appropriate. In cases similar to this, it's far more likely that you'll want to have multiple users belonging to a single company.